# how to click a specific div and get information from it asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am making a table for schedule  and putting div's on the table. People can make new  appointments by clicking on one of the `div` .

I am changing the activeview when a div is clicked. I need to embed information in the div's so I can use it in the database and I want to know which div is clicked.

How can I solve this? Here is my code:

```
HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "60px");
div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.MarginTop, "1px");
div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "green");
div.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, last * 40 + "px");
div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "somefunction()");
div.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");
bul.Controls.Add(div);
```

`bul` is a table cell where I put a DIV.

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but why are you generating the HTML in the code behind? It would seem you'd be much better off placing this in the markup and adding the appropriate JavaScript there to asynchronously post back to the server.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to set an ID in your div server control

see this url which explains you how reference your server control in javascript:

http://encosia.com/2007/08/08/robust-aspnet-control-referencing-in-javascript/

Excerpt from article:

```
$get('<%= yourdiv.ClientID %>')


<script>
  alert('yourdiv has a value of: ' + $get('<%= yourdiv.ClientID %>').value);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> .answer {
width:20px;
height:20px;
border-color:Red;
border:1px;
background-color:Green;

HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
div.ID = "testDiv";
div.Attributes.Add("class", "answer");
div.Attributes.Add("onclick", "somefunction(this)");
this.Controls.Add(div);  // this code shlould be on pageload

 <script language="javascript">
        function somefunction(obj)
        {
            alert(obj.id);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you need to rethink about your approach.
I think you will need to seperate the solution into 3 different parts:

1- Server-side code: which will get the information about current appointments, and to save the new appointment that your audience may create.

2- Markup code: which should contain the basic building blocks for your markup, and not to generate everything from your server-side code, as @Senfo has suggested.

3- You should use some client-side code (Javascript) in order to switch between the normal-view mode, and the create-view mode.

4- if you don't want to use client-side code, you should decorate your div with 2 attributes in order to be able to deal with them in your C# code:

- ID (which should be unique per every div)
- `Runat="Server"` attribute

I know that my solution is not complete, but considering that this is a homework question, I think it's better to guide you to the correct path, but to let you move on according to these principles.
I think you can make it, and you should now create a much cleaner solution.

if you still can't figure it out, I will try to give you an example, but my advice is to take a deep breath, and start by your own :)

Comment: this isnt a homework. this is just a part of a little project(  a structure similiar to daypilot calendar [link](http://www.daypilot.org/calendar.html)). im just not good at .net . Can you give me an example so i can figure it easier out. thank you